# Getting custom ValidationAttribute to work web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Working in c# WebApi2.1 I run into the following issue. Trying to get a custom validation attribute to work.

```
   public class NullableDateTimeAsStringAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Do this to see if this get called ...");
        }
    }
```

I did annotate a model with the attribute like this:

```
public class Tiger

    {
        public String name;
        [NullableDateTimeAsString]
        public String BirthDay;
    }
```

Binding works.

Problem is that the code doesnt get called... The HttpGet returns without validation error...

Question 1:
Do I need to do something specific to make this custom validation attribute work or should it work once the attribute is being used on a model?

Question 2:
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know why or how, but further testing showed that the code does get called in my real scenario. Just not in my test setup. Must have made some mistake somewhere.
To answer my first question:
no, besides using the attribute, nothing additional needs to be done to to get the custom validator to work.
Strange thing though is that debugging does not seem to work...

Comment: Those things as validation on controller cannot be easily and fully unit tested. As it is done by WepApi Pipeline, not a controller itself.